# Making a winforms picturebox animation that moves at a different speed, within a different animation

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, animation

I'm trying to make the image rotate if it falls in the first if statement. This works, but it rotates extremely fast (due to the animation being 60fps, so it rotates 60 times/s). How can I separate it so that it moves downward the same as the rest but the rotation is nice and slow? Multithreading is the obvious approach here but anything I've tried (pretty much anything you can get out of google or chatgpt in 2 hours) results in access errors because there are two different threads modifying the same object. [Here is a short clip to demonstrate the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0G2fmd1jAWY) and [here is the repo](https://github.com/OblivionNoirV2/DesktopWeather), if that helps.

```
        public void AniLoop()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer loop = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            //60fps
            loop.Interval = 16;
            loop.Tick += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                Animate(precip_type);
            };
            loop.Start();
        }
        //setup values shared by all precip types 
        static int list_index;
        static List<PictureBox> temp_list;
        static Rectangle hit_detection;
        static bool hit_edge;
        static Random rn_index;
        //shared between all precip types, with rotation added for snow
        public void Animate(string pt)
        {   
            rn_index = new Random();
            rn_index.Next(0, precalculations_list.Count - 1);
            temp_list = picture_boxes.ToList();
            hit_detection = pm.ClientRectangle;
            hit_edge = false;
            foreach (PictureBox pb in temp_list)
            {
                list_index = rn_index.Next(0, precalculations_list.Count - 1);
                pb.Top += added_pix_int + precalculations_list[list_index];
                pb.Left += s_d;
   
                if (pt != "Rain")
                {
                    Image img = pb.Image;
                    img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    pb.Image = img;

                }

                //when one touches the edge of the screen, clear the list/boxes 
                if (pb.Left < hit_detection.Left ||
                    pb.Right > hit_detection.Right ||
                    pb.Bottom > hit_detection.Bottom)
                {
                    pm.Controls.Remove(pb);
                    picture_boxes.Remove(pb);
                    hit_edge = true;
                }

            }
            //cannot modify collection, so happens afterward
            //todo: check if hit left or right too, if skew is active
            if (hit_edge && picture_boxes.Count < img_count)
            {
                temp_list.Clear();
                AddBoxes();

            }
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only instantiate Random ONCE.

Change:

```
static Random rn_index;
```

To:

```
static Random rn_index = new Random();
```

and get rid of the line creating a Random in your animate() method.

If you want them to rotate at a different speed from the Tick() event, you could create a `DateTime` var that holds the next time they should rotate. Whenever you're past that, perform the rotation and reset for the next target time:

```
static int rotationDelay = 200;
static DateTime nextRotation = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(rotationDelay);
```

In your animate():

```
bool rotate = (DateTime.Now >= nextRotation);
foreach (PictureBox pb in temp_list)
{
    list_index = rn_index.Next(0, precalculations_list.Count - 1);
    pb.Top += added_pix_int + precalculations_list[list_index];
    pb.Left += s_d;

    if (pt != "Rain" && rotate)
    {
        Image img = pb.Image;
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        pb.Image = img;
    }

    //when one touches the edge of the screen, clear the list/boxes 
    if (pb.Left < hit_detection.Left ||
        pb.Right > hit_detection.Right ||
        pb.Bottom > hit_detection.Bottom)
    {
        pm.Controls.Remove(pb);
        picture_boxes.Remove(pb);
        hit_edge = true;
    }

}
if (rotate) {
    nextRotation = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(rotationDelay);
}
```

Comment: Note that this only works "well" because the main Timer has a low Interval of 16, which is really fast, and this allows you to determine that the current time is past the target time rather quickly. If the main interval Timer Interval was slower than the Rotation Interval it'd be a different situation.